# a global variable cannot be assigned twice

Tags: c, global-variables, memory-access

I have faced some problem when doing TDD.
I designed this function:

```
String *subString;

String *getWordAndUpdate(String *line, char *delimiter) {
    String *word = malloc(sizeof(String));
    int i;

    stringLeftTrim(line);

    word->length = 0;
    word->startIndex = 0;

    for(i = line->startIndex; i < line->length; i++) {
        if(line->rawString[i] != ' ') {
            word->rawString[i] = line->rawString[i];
            line->startIndex++;
            word->length++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    line->length = line->length - i;

    return word;
}
```

With my String struct:

```
typedef struct {
    char *rawString;
    int startIndex;
    int length;
} String;
```

When I call this getWordAndUpdate function the first time it works fine, but when i call second time it says bad memory access.

```
extern String *subString;
void test_getWordAndUpdate_should_get_the_first_word_from_a_line_of_instruction() {
    String oneLineString = {"movwf 0x10", 0, 10};

    subString = getWordAndUpdate(&oneLineString, " ,;"); // works fine

    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('m', subString->rawString[0]);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('o', subString->rawString[1]);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('v', subString->rawString[2]);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('w', subString->rawString[3]);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL('f', subString->rawString[4]);
    TEST_ASSERT_NOT_EQUAL(' ', subString->rawString[5]);
    TEST_ASSERT_NOT_EQUAL('0', subString->rawString[6]);
    TEST_ASSERT_NOT_EQUAL('x', subString->rawString[7]);
    TEST_ASSERT_NOT_EQUAL('1', subString->rawString[8]);
    TEST_ASSERT_NOT_EQUAL('0', subString->rawString[9]);

    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(5, oneLineString.startIndex);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(5, oneLineString.length);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(0, subString->startIndex);
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(5, subString->length);

    subString = getWordAndUpdate(&oneLineString, " ,;"); // bad memory access
}
```

Comment: I think you need to go over your code first, and fix what appear to be some major problems: 1. Function `getWordAndUpdate` makes no use of the `delimiter` argument... 2. Your second call to this function result with a memory leak... 3. You don't seem to be allocating the `rawString` array anywhere... And there are probably a few more problems...

Answer (score 1):

You function `getWordAndUpdate` modify your object oneLineString in theses lines of code:

```
line->length--;
line->startIndex++;
```

So, when you call it a second times, your object in not consistent.

Try to make a copy of oneLineString or find an algo that not modify your parameter.

Maybe, you can use this kind of function:

```
String *subString;

String *getWordAndUpdate(String *line, char *delimiter) {
    String *word = malloc(sizeof(String));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; line->rawString[i] != ' '; ++i)
        word->rawString[i] = line->rawString[i];
    word->length = i;

    return word;
}
```

And you don't take care yet of your delimiter parameter.